# Why is '0' treated as a true value in an if statement in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

It is my understanding that zero is a False value. Then why is it being treated as a True value in the following code, i.e, why is 'a being returned ?

```
scm> (if 0 'a 'b)
'a
```

Comment: "It is my understanding that zero is a False value." According to whom?

Answer (score 5):

In Scheme the *only* false value is `#f` (although sometimes the `false` alias is also defined with the same value), anything else is considered true - including: `0`, `""`, `'()`, etc. So clearly in this expression:

```
(if 0 'a 'b)
```

The value `0` is truthy, therefore the whole expression evaluates to `'a` as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Different languages make different decisions about whether non-boolean values can be treated as booleans, and which ones count as `True` vs `False`. For a comparison of the behaviors in some languages, see [here](http://langnostic.inaimathi.ca/article?name=truthy-and-falsy.html).

Scheme is a language that makes the decision:

- you may use non-boolean values in contexts that require booleans
- any value other than the canonical false symbol `#f` is truthy.

Answer (score 0):

Most LISPers have the same feeling about the empty list. Since the beginning for LISP `nil`/`()` was also the only false value. Scheme introduced `#f` as false and kept `()` as false for several reports until they removed `()` as a false value. Thus only `#f` is considered false.

You can't change the report easily so I suggest you make a procedure to do what you want:

```
(define (boolean x)
  (not (or (eq? x '())
           (eq? x #f)
           (eqv? x "")
           (eqv? x 0))))

(boolean "")           ; ==> #f
(if (boolean 0) 'a 'b) ; ==> b
```

Alternatively if you use this a lot you can make yourself a macro:

```
(define-syntax mif
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ predicate consequent alternative)
     (if (boolean predicate) consequent alternative))))

(mif 0 'a 'b) ; ==> b
```

With R6RS and R7RS you can do this in a library and rename this out as `if` together with `(except (rnrs) if)` and then you can import this instead of `(rnrs)` and get this `if` behavior instead of standard. Notice that you cannot change what `if` is used by withing rnrs or other libraries so you need to make yoru own versions of all special forms which behave differently than what you want. People reading your code might get confused.